# Are Java static members initilized after static block?

Tags: java, static-methods, static-members

Is there a reason where static final variable will not be instantiated before the static block?

So in the example I provided will print:

```
someVar value= null
```

Instead of:

```
 someVar value=SomeValue
```

I saw this behavior today, In my application,

I am trying to reproduce - unsuccessfully - I do see the value of the static member...

```
class SomeClass{
    static final String someVar ="SomeValue";

    static{
         System.out.println("someVar value=" + someVar );
   }

public static void main(String[] args){     
    new SomeClass();
}

}
```

Comment: i think the order matters. to where if the static block comes first it is executed first. why dont you try it out?

Comment: when the member is after the method there is a compilation problem: Cannot reference a field before it is defined

Comment: I believe both static and instance initializer blocks are executed, along with field initializations, in text order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of initialization is given in [JSL #12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2):

For static initialization:

- Execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

For construction:

- Evaluate the arguments and process that superclass constructor invocation recursively
- Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code for the class.
- Execute the rest of the body of this constructor.

Note that initializer blocks and variable initializers are considered together, not separately.

Answer (score 0):

I would to say, it depend on your code sequence. Run following code in your local, it will tell you the answer.

```
public class SomeClass{
    static final String someVar ="SomeValue";
    static final StaticMember staticMem = new StaticMember(1);

    static{
        System.out.println("someVar value=" + someVar );
    }

    static final StaticMember staticMem2 = new StaticMember(2);

    public static void main(String[] args){     
        new SomeClass();
    }

}

class StaticMember {
    StaticMember(int num) {
        System.out.println("StaticMember constructor " + num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an order the jvm will excecute and instanciate always in this priority:

1. Static Blocks
2. Static Members
3. Instance Blocks
4. Instance Members
5. Constructor

If you have inheritance the instanciation order will be a little bit different:

1. Parent Static Block
2. Parent Static Members
3. Child Static Block
4. Child Static Members
5. Parent Non-Static Members
6. Child Non-Static Members
7. Parent Constructor
8. Child Constructor

I hope this clarifies a little your issue.

Comment: So if static block is first to instantiate - why for the simple case above, the print statement print its value...

Comment: In the example above it will print `null` because the member someVar has not been instanciated yet, the static block will run before someVar is instanciated.

Comment: No, I just execute the code - JRE7 - its printing its value...

Comment: I think I know the reason why, a object "String" will be created at the moment of the compilation called a String pool that is why the object is there before the static block.

Comment: Initializer blocks and member initializers are not separated as stated here. See JLS #12.4.2.